# How to convert text-shadow so IE9 will work

Tags: internet-explorer-9, css

How would I set the text-shadow property in ie9 to match the other browsers like I've got it below?

How to use .sysMenu-item text-shadow

```
.sysMenu-item{padding:8px;padding-top:7px;height:110%;float:left; 
              border-right:.2em groove #fff;margin-top:-2px; cursor:  pointer;
              text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.64);
}
```

--in ie9?

I need the above text-shadow to work in the below css3

```
html.ie9 .sysMenu-item {
    background-color: white;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(color=rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.64)) 
            progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=100) 
            progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(color=#ffffff,offX=1,offY=1)
            progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(color=#ffffff,offX=-1,offY=1)
            progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(color=#ffffff,offX=1,offY=-1)
            progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(color=#ffffff,offX=-1,offY=-1);
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are going to need to use jquery, something like this http://kilianvalkhof.com/2008/javascript/text-shadow-in-ie-with-jquery/

Check out this article as well: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/28/css3-solutions-for-internet-explorer/